# Website tracking cookies

Tags: web, ads, tracker

I read about website tracking cookies at "http://www.newfangled.com/unlimited_vs_limited_web_tracking" and am wondering how they are implemented.

On page 2 of the article, the author writes, "third-party trackers using beacon technology can match the data they collect about you in real time with other databases containing geolocation, financial, and medical information in order to expand your profile to predict your age, gender, zip code, income, marital status, parenthood, home ownership, as well as unique interests."

I've thought of a few ways trackers could be implemented and am hoping answers to the following questions will help me get some clarity about how trackers work.

When you visit a website, do all of your cookies become available to the website? E.g., if I visited StackO.com , would the site be able to access my facebook/google/other cookies?

To track your visits from site to site, do various websites share information in a database, i.e. when you visit FB, google, CNN...do they log your activity in a shared database that's accessible by companies in the group?

Answer (score 0):

> When you visit a website, do all of your cookies become available to the website?

[Yes](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html)

> To track your visits from site to site, do various websites share information in a database, ie when you visit FB, google, CNN...do they log your activity in a shared database that's accessible by companies in the group?

[Yes](http://www.networkadvertising.org/choices/)

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes. If you look at cookies set by CNN.com for example, there's cookies set for scorecardresearch.com domain:

http://webcookies.info/cookies/cnn.com/11993/

Then there's some JavaScript code or 1x1 image that actually creates a request to the scorecardresearch.com servers. This way Scorecard Research can track you as you move from CNN to other websites. And they will definitely aggregate the information from various websites using their technology.

Profiling is just making use of this aggregated behavioral data.